# Can't import Sequelize models with TypeScript: Error: No Sequelize instance passed

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My `user.model.ts` is:

```
@Table
export class User extends Model<User> {
    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    firstName: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    lastName: string;
...
```

When I try to import it:

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.database, DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.username, DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.password, { dialect: 'postgres' })
    const modelFile = require(path.join(modelPath, 'user.model')).User.init({ sequelize })

    console.log(modelFile)
```

I get an error: `Error: No Sequelize instance passed`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequelize instance must be passed in the second argument of the `init`
method

```
const User = require(path.join(modelPath, 'user.model'));
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.database,
    DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.username,
    DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.password, {
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
)
User.init(modelAttributesObject, { sequelize })
```

But as you are using the sequelize TypeScript, you can initialize your models with the instance

```
const User = require(path.join(modelPath, 'user.model'));
const sequelize = sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'postgres',
    database: DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.database,
    username: DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.username,
    password: DB_CREDENTIALS_PARSED.database,
    models: [User]
});
```

Comment: But isn't `modelAttributesObject` coming from my definition?

Comment: Yes it is, that is why you don't need the ìnit` method here as it require the attributes to be passed as first argument. Either you use the TypeScript version and passe models to sequelize instance or the Javascript version and use the `init` method

Comment: With the `Typescript` version, what about relationships?

Comment: "Relations can be described directly in the model" from the sequelize-typescript. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#model-association

Comment: So as long as I include all the models, everything should just work?

Comment: Yes, note the difference in the TypeScrpit version you passe an object to sequelize

Comment: I get: `Argument of type '{ dialect: "postgres"; database: any; username: any; password: any; host: any; models: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213209/discussion-between-mousto090-and-shamoon).